# I want to fix the error in the following code

Tags: tables, errors

```
\documentclass[a4,CEJM,PDF]{cej}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amscd}
\begin{document}
\def\Mc[#1]#2#3{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\mc#1#2{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|cc|c}
    \cline{1-8}
              \mc{|c|}{3}  &&             &&                     &&                     & & 3     \\[6pt]\cline{1-1}
            & \mc{c|}{2}  && \mc{c|}{2}  && \mc{c|}{2}          && \mc{c|}{1}          & &       \cline{1-8}
              \mc{|c|}{1}  &&  \mc{c|}{3} && \mc{c|}{3}          &&                     & & 7     \\[6pt]\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
            & \mc{c|}{10} && \mc{c|}{8}  && \mc{c|}{5}          && \mc{c|}{4}          & &       \cline{1-8}
                          &&             && \mc{c|}{1}          && \mc{c|}{4}          & & 5     \\[6pt]\cline{5-5}\cline{7-7} 
            & \mc{c|}{7}  && \mc{c|}{6}  && \mc{c|}{6}          && \mc{c|}{8}          & &       \cline{1-8}
              \Mc[2]{c}{4} & \Mc[2]{c}{3} & \Mc[2]{c}{4}         & \Mc[2]{c}{4}        & &    
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

and I have the following error

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...ip \tabrightsep \relax \endtemplate 

l.198 ...|}{2}          && \mc{c|}{1}          & &
                                                         \cline{1-8}
? 
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...ip \tabrightsep \relax \endtemplate 

l.200 ...|}{5}          && \mc{c|}{4}          & &
                                                         \cline{1-8}
? 
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...ip \tabrightsep \relax \endtemplate 

l.202 ...|}{6}          && \mc{c|}{8}          & &
                                                         \cline{1-8}
? 
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...ip \tabrightsep \relax \endtemplate 

l.203 ...]{c}{4}         & \Mc[2]{c}{4}        & &
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the error you get? And please always make a complete compilable example (with documentclass, necessary usepackages and the document environment).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You havent defined commands `\mc` and `\MC`.

Comment: \def\Mc[#1]#2#3{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\mc#1#2{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

Comment: please edit your question and add your come into your MWE. You also need to explain what error you got. so far is not seems anything wrong (beside missing command definition that the table is unnecessary complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Your code having many errors, below is the corrected code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|cc|c}
\cline{1-8}
          \mc{|c|}{3}  &&             &&                     &&                     & & 3     \\[6pt]\cline{1-1}
        & \mc{c|}{2}  && \mc{c|}{2}  && \mc{c|}{2}          &&
        \mc{c|}{1}          & \\      \cline{1-8}
          \mc{|c|}{1}  &&  \mc{c|}{3} && \mc{c|}{3}          &&                     & & 7     \\[6pt]\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
        & \mc{c|}{10} && \mc{c|}{8}  && \mc{c|}{5}          && \mc{c|}{4}          & \\       \cline{1-8}
                      &&             && \mc{c|}{1}          && \mc{c|}{4}          & & 5     \\[6pt]\cline{5-5}\cline{7-7} 
        & \mc{c|}{7}  && \mc{c|}{6}  && \mc{c|}{6}          && \mc{c|}{8}          & \\       \cline{1-8}
          \Mc[2]{c}{4} & \Mc[2]{c}{3} & \Mc[2]{c}{4}         & \Mc[2]{c}{4}        & \\    
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I think you should at least mention the most important errors and how you solved them.

Comment: @TeXnician I thought he may compare his code and the corrected code, anyhow, the error was, he misused many & characters in table body